# Image pattern recognition - Suggested environment?

Tags: c#, java, pattern-recognition

I need to do some work that include pattern recognition.

Wanted to ask whether anyone can give me a suggestion of what language is stronger for image pattern recognition? Java, C#..

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose Matlab if it is among your options. It has a framework for working with images, and other frameworks for pattern recognition. So everything is in it and you don't need third-party software.

If Java and C# are your only options, they have image APIs, but they don't have anything built-in for working with pattern recognition, so you will have to depend on third-party frameworks. I would not say that either language is stronger than the other for this purpose.

(And as Java and C# are fairly equally easy, it comes down to personal preference)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is pretty amazing when it comes to images. It also has a lot of included pattern recognition stuff from feature extraction up to pattern recognition.

I used it in two bigger image recognition projects last semester.

While seems like a pretty weird language at the start it gets really powerful once you get into it.

If you are a student they have a pretty cheap licence for you.

There are pattern recognition APIs for all major languages, but Matlab is a language specifically designed for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score -2):

imho there is no difference, in which language you implement your algorithms. maybe java is easyer to handle, but C would be a little faster.